# What's more memory efficient IIFE in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-efficient, iife, self-invoking-function

I want to invoke an anonymous self-executing function, **only when dom is ready**, with the more memory-efficient technique. And also, I want to use locally-scoped versions of window and window.jQuery global Objects, for optimization (loading local scope it's faster than global).

So, it's this pattern correct?

```
;!(function(window, $) {
    $(function(){
        // your code here
    }); 
})(window,window.jQuery);
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `!` is used to force an expression, you already have the IIFE wrapped in parentheses, which form an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would just look a little better IMO:

```
;(function(window, $, undefined) {
    $(function(){
       // your code here
    }); 
})(window,jQuery);
```